# Rope and Pulley

Tags: animation, 3d-cursor

I am new to blender and for my project, I must make a Rude Goldberg machine. I am currently struggling with the rope and a pulley part and don't know how to even start it. Can someone please help?

Comment: First of all help us to understand better your problem. Please add some screenshot of what you want to achieve and what do you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. Rope and pulley animations are fairly complex, using several physics simulations - even just modeling rope can be a challenge. But Rube Goldberg machines don't have to have pulley mechanics. They just have to be enormously over-engineered for a simple task. So simple rotations and collision physics can be enough to make a decent machine. Also... I suggest avoiding using BSE to do your homework for you :) Try this tutorial from BlenderGuru on Rigid Body Simulations - https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics